# Grids not showing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have a problem in my local pc with some grids in an asp.net website.
The first image is the testing server, and the grids are showing ok here.
The second image is the same page (sabe website, same vs solution) running on my pc(localhost).

What can be missing in my pc??

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your CSS seems to be pointing to the wrong location. Check your console (F12) to see if you have any `.css` files that are not loading.

Comment: check you css.. also make sure your browser allows javascript..

Comment: @Michael_B is right, it has to do with your CSS. The data is all there but thre seems to be no styling. Look at firebug or F12 console and you should see the errors.

Comment: I dont think it has to do with the css, because the menu bar and other items are showing ok with the correct styles, y checked with F12 and the css is fine. Could it be something with the grids that I have to install or something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought would be to check whether the CSS file you are linking to is accessible in your local environment.  Look in the source view of your web browser.  You could also pull up IE Developer Tools (F12) and click the CSS tab.

Comment: I dont think it has to do with the css, because the menu bar and other items are showing ok with the correct styles, y checked with F12 and the css is fine.
Could it be something with the grids that I have to install or something?
Thanks